# Tomcat In Apache

Tags: apache, tomcat

I am trying to include tomcate in apache, following the steps in the below link

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.2-doc/uguide/tomcat_ug.html.

In that link they mention after the tomcat starts there will be a file tomcat-apache.conf inside the tomcat\conf directory but am not able to find it. Am using tomcat 6 binary.

Am i using the right tomcat or should get a different one??

Comment: Don't look at Tomcat 3.2 docs...

Comment: Those docs are for Tomcat 3.2.  Find something more appropriate to Tomcat 6.

Comment: Try to use "apache-tomcat-6.0.35".

Comment: I tried using apache tomcat 6.0.35 also, after starting it i still dont find the tomcat-apache.conf file.. Can Anybody suggest me a link or help me in configuring apache to serve static content and tomcat to serve the jsp/servlets.

Answer (score 0):

if your are on windows , you can easily use XAMPP for windows it supports and included tomcat and it is configured and u can just use it